# Google Chrome [v23] prevents opening of multiple new tabs via javascript - how to override?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome [v23] prevents the opening of multiple new tabs via javascript [don't ask, but this is how my client wants his app to work, sometimes it's necessary to open 2-5 new tabs (with URLs in them) due to reasons]. This worked fine, until Chrome v23 was released.

So my question is: How to override this security (?) behaviour ?

Comment: Go to "Settings" --> "Content settings" --> "Popups" --> "Exceptions", add here your domain.

Comment: @ComFreek Unfortunatly this does not work. The "tabs" will be openend as popups, which is not what the client accepts.